# How to use generic view with pk renamed

Tags: python, django, django-views

`django.views.generic.detail.DetailView` uses `pk` or `slug` from `urls.py` as the identifier. In my case, I have:

`urls.py`:

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:quiz_id>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view()),
]
```

Is there a way to use:

```py
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Quiz
```

without changing `quiz_id` to `pk` (default name used for primary key)?

I expect that there is some way to change the vague `pk` to something more descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [ancestors (MRO)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView), there is `django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin` listed. You can override [`pk_url_kwarg` of this class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg) to change `pk` to `quiz_id`:

```py
class ResultsView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Quiz
    pk_url_kwarg = "quiz_id"
```